# Boostrap - Center content in middle of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center

I am having a little trouble with my site (http://www.addatidjani.com/)

I would like to make the content to center vertically and horizontally on each page.

I have tried to give it a width and an height, positioning the element absolutely and offsetting them but then they lose their responsiveness.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See how to center anything in CSS!

[Center Anything!](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/)